# querying mysql from a php class

Tags: php, mysql, class

I'm doing a query from inside a php class like this

```
<?php
require_once('abstractTable.php');
class User_Orders extends AbstractTable{
public static function get_by_month($month, $year){
$query = "select * from `user_orders` where month(`date_order`) = '2' and year(`date_order`) = '2012'";
return self::getObjectList(self::$class, $query);
}
?>
```

this is the getObjectList()

```
public static function getObjectList($class, $q){
        $arrClass = array();
        $result = mysql_query($q) or die( "error: ".mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $arrClass[] = new $class($row);
            }
        }
        //echo $q;
        return $arrClass;
    }
```

And when that script is executed I got error message like this:

error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

My question is, is putting query inside a class like that allowed?

Thank you

Comment: Anytime I'm having this kind of errors , I run the query in `phpmyadmin` in order to check if it's the query's fault or my php code's fault.

Comment: Why don't you test your query directly to your SQL server and see what's exactly the error is?

Comment: the query is okay. it works in the sql server. it's just when I run that php script, i keep on getting that error.

Comment: show the contents of `getObjectList()` I think it might have some role onto this problem

Comment: Could you post the `getObjectList` code or preferebly the whole class

Comment: Are the values `2` and `2012` actually hard-coded, or are they actually `$month` and `$year` variables (which might be empty)? Also, note that you're not able to use indexes because of functions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: it was '$month' and '$year' then i ran into that error, so i tried to hard code to test, but the error's still there

Comment: yes, added the getObjectList() function there :)

Answer (score 0):

It is "allowed". Try running it from a console.

Try this:

```
$query = "select * from user_orders where month(date_order) = 2 and year(date_order) = 2012;";
```

Comment: the query works. I think the problem lies within the way I put the query inside the php class. perhaps.

Comment: In order to debug this you could print the `$q` variable when printing the error to see the actual query you're running

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the month and year functions return an integer type, so try removing the quotes from '2' and '2012'.

Comment: Mysql does it for you. So no need to worry about this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "select * from user_orders where month(date_order)=2 and year(date_order)=2012";
```

It should work...

Comment: What is the difference from my previously posted answer?

Comment: @MostyMostacho : **Point 1** : You have `;` in double codes at the end and I think that won't work...  **Point 2** : I didn't even copied your query.. GOT THAT??? I just had a look at your query... **Point 3** : I had already drafted the query, but due to diconnectio of Internet, I posted late...